# AB testing with caching ON\OFF

Tags: performance

I'm having weird benchmarking results with my drupal site.
The command I used (from my home PC) is:

> ab -n 100 -c 10 http://www.mysite.it/

Results with **caching disabled**:

> Document Path:          /
>   **Document Length:        69903 bytes**
>
> .... cut ....
>
> 1.5 requests/second
>
> very long times (about 10s)

Results with **caching enabled**:

> Document Path:          /
>   **Document Length:        197 bytes**
>
> .... cut ....
>
> 25 requests/second
>
> very short times (about 0.5s)

Such a huge difference in requests per second and connection times is hard to believe, but MIGHT be true. 
But why is the page with caching enabled only 197 bytes?

Comment: _But why is the page with caching enabled only 197 bytes?_ Only you can answer that, it's your site! Are you saying there's data missing from your requests with caching enabled? Is the request the same size when you inspect it with dev tools as it is using `ab`?

Comment: What happens when you turn off page compression in Admin » Config » Development » Performance? This option is only visible when the page caching is turned on.

Comment: Well, using a browser, i can see exactly the same page regardless of caching, so I think it's pretty impossible to have such a huge difference. By dev tools you mean the devel module? I've enabled it but it only gives me memory usage and query execution time

Comment: Sorry no, I meant dev tools in the browser. Chrome's Network tab, for example

Comment: Using chrome's network tab, i tested the homepage with caching enabled (compression ON), caching enabled (compression OFF), caching disabled. I always get the same size (16.1kb, 72.7 with content)

Comment: So it looks like you're getting incorrect values back from `ab` then?

Comment: @Sifro: When testing page-cache related things: Remember to logout before examining request results. If you get identical size for compressed and uncompressed pages, then either compression is not available on your server or your testing method is deficient.